# Check if $2^{2^n}=O(2^n)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I want to check if $2^{2^n}=O(2^n)$.

That's what I have tried:

Let $4^n=O(2^n)$.

Then, $\exists c_1>0, n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_1$:

$$4^n \leq c \cdot 2^n$$
$$$$

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{4^n}{2^n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \frac{4}{2}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} 2^n=+\infty$$

This means that $2^n=o(4^n)$, i.e. $\forall c>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$:

$$2^n<c \cdot 4^n$$

So, we conclude that we cannot find a $c_1>0$ such that $4^n \leq c \cdot 2^n$.

Therefore, the equality $2^{2^n}=O(2^n)$ does not hold.

Could you tell me if it is right or if I have done something wrong?

Comment: $$(2^2)^{n}=2^{2n}\neq2^{2^n}$$

Comment: Your argument is good for showing $4^n$ is not $O(2^n)$, however as integrator pointed out, $4^n \ll 2^{2^n}$.  It can be salvaged by adding an extra line showing that $4^n = o(2^{2^n})$ and so by transitivity of $o$, you have that $2^n = o(2^{2^n})$.  In the case that you are not familiar with what Integrator points out, note that towering exponents without parenthesis are assumed to be read top-down, ie $2^{2^n} = 2^{(2^n)}$

Comment: @JMoravitz So, can we do it like that?
$$$$
We set $2^n=u$
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2^{2^n}}{4^n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2^{2^n}}{2^{2n}}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2^u}{u^2}=\lim_{n \to =\infty} \frac{2^u \ln 2}{2u}=\lim_{n \to =\infty} \frac{2^{2u} \ln^2 2}{2}=+\infty$$

So, $4^n=o(2^{2^n})$

$$2^n=o(4^n) \\ 4^n=o(2^{2^n}) \\ \Rightarrow 2^n=o(2^{2^n})$$

So, it cannot be $2^{2^n}=O(2^n)$.

Comment: @evinda If you were to go through that trouble, it may be easiest to start over and show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{2^n}}{2^n} = \infty$ as it will use far fewer steps (only one application of l'hopitals and removal of unnecessary lines involving $4^n$).  You've already done most of the work for it.  Setting $u=2^n$ will make it $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^u}{u}$

Comment: @JMoravitz
So, is it like that?

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2^{2^n}}{2^n}=\lim_{u \to +\infty} \frac{2^u}{u}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2^u \ln 2}{1}=+\infty$$
$$$$
So, $2^n=o(2^{2^n})$ and so it cannot be $2^{2^n}=O(2^n)$.

Comment: that is it precisely.

Comment: @JMoravitz Nice!!! Thank you very much!!! :)